# How register and use methods from C# in Lua

Tags: c#, lua

At the moment I am working as a Lua scripter while doing C#, there is some need to implement my functionality in C# and connect it to Lua. The best way is to include `".dll"` file in Lua script via require/dofile. I don't need to call the script via `LuaInterface-DoFile`, I need the dll to be usable as a module

In C# I tried to use DllExport with the `luaopen` prefix, but nothing came of it. What are the solutions to connect .dll from a Lua script

Comment: You have to build DLL with function [`luaopen_yourlib`](https://www.lua.org/pil/26.2.html) in it.  IDK if it is possible in C#.